# Why is '/?' added to URL after successful post call

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am running two servers locally,
First server is running on 8080 port and has the REST calls (GET, POST)
Second server is NPM running on 65321 port and has REACT application

Scenario:
I am making a POST call to http://localhost:8080/postData/ from http://localhost:65132/ REACT client application using axios library. The post call is successful and I can see that the new object got created, but the problem is, after the successful POST operation, the WHOLE application gets refreshed and the control does not go to the "then" method of axios. I see that "/?" gets appended to the URL, http://localhost:65132/?

I don't want the whole application to be refreshed after the POST. Is it due to CORS? But surprisingly I am not getting any errors related to CORS.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other's benefit if you come across such a scenario, after debugging the front end and backend code, the culprit was the backend.
The redirection from the backend was adding a /? due to a bug and the browser was trying to render this, meaning, it was refreshing after the operation was successful